# Building MacOS 10.8 source code on 10.6

Tags: c#, monodevelop, foundation, monomac, nsusernotification

I am trying to [build SparkleShare on Mac](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/blob/master/SparkleShare/Mac/README.md).

- I have Mac OS 10.6
- SparkleShare claims to run on [Snow Leopard (10.6) or later](http://sparkleshare.org)
- SparkleShare contains calls to `NSUserNotification`, a class which is [Available in OS X v10.8 and later](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012259)

Monodevelop throws an error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NSUserNotification' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

In Monodevelop, when I begin typing `MonoMac.Foundation.NSUser`, the only suggested item is `NSUserDefaults`, `NSUserNotification` is not suggested.

Is this kind of cross-compilation possible?
I can't upgrade to 10.8 because I also want to check how the user experience is on 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/monomac
git clone https://github.com/mono/maccore
cd monomac
make
```

It should generate `MonoMac.dll`. Copy it to wherever your `MonoMac.dll` is, restart Monodevelop, the project should now build fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at MonoMac's source code, and `NSUserNotification` is a recent addition, it has been added three months ago: https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/2c4a8c639254705e0dde1ce32f4e49cfcb72187e.

These are the generated files:

- [NSUserNotification.g.cs](http://pastebin.com/FUvfP1GB)
- [NSUserNotificationCenter.g.cs](http://pastebin.com/0qJGGknH)
- [NSUserNotificationActivationType](http://pastebin.com/8P3D7H1Q)
- [NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate.g.cs](http://pastebin.com/abRkHBMS)

As a workaround for older MonoMac versions, you can simply copy these into your code.